# Modify Firefox mimetypes.rdf to prompt Open With for application/octet-stream

Tags: firefox, mime-types

Some web-servers intentionally or inadvertently use the `application/octet-stream` mime-type for files where either the actual mime-type isn't known or when they are incorrectly configured.  Or perhaps where the file is binary and `application/octet-stream` is appropriate.

With these mimetypes, the `Open With` option is omitted from the file download dialog box.

I would like to modify Firefox mimetype.rdf (or whatever else is needed) to change this behaviour so that "Open With" option is always present.

I have skimmed the Mozilla docs and monkeyed with the rdf a bit, but I am hoping someone has already figured this out.

Of course, if there is an extension I cannot find that just does this already, excellent.

Comment: What OS are you using? In my Windows 7 with Firefox 10.0.2, even `application/octet-stream` mime type prompted me with an `Open With` window. but in Linux, I follow [the tutorial](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf) and nothing works.

Comment: @MdGao I found this to be happening on linux - the stupid thing is I no longer access the system that was giving me the problem.   Do you have a link I can test against?

Comment: if you mean download link for test: [this](http://cachefly.cachefly.net/100mb.test), and [this](http://www.linode.com/speedtest/)

Comment: In recent versions up to the current 32.0.3 on Linux I have the option `Open with` but it remembers only a single executable in the pull-down menu so it is very hardly usable when you have to find the right executable file almost every time. --- Unfortunately I did not manage yet to make OpenDownload² working completely as expected (opens `.pcapng` in `gedit` instead of `wireshark`).

Comment: I tried editing the mimeTypes.rdf adding handling of application/octet-stream, but that did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the experimental extension [OpenDownload²](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/opendownload-10902/?src=collection&collection_id=9992ca79-862b-d5d2-6446-4deef37177b2) :

> OpenDownload² inserts a "Run" button into the "Open File" dialog when
>   downloading files. Clicking the button saves the particular file in
>   your temporary directory and opens it with the assigned application or
>   (for .exe files) runs the application from there.

Comment: Yeah, it works - not quite what I want, as I'd prefer to be able to pick the app that it uses, but at least it will defer to the OS for file types it knows.

Comment: Seems a bit scary that it will just execute a file, regardless of the file type. Couldn't you accidentally run untrusted code if you mistake a exe file for a PDF?